# Best (free/open source) mock up tools?

Tags: open-source, prototype, mockup-tool

I am looking for a very good (easy to use, good drawings) mockup tool that allows u to draw up page prototype pages.

I know of pencil, but I use an x64 firefox which I ve not found a pencil plugin for (Any one with pointers to where I can get one?)

I ve also heard of MockingBird which is available online (pls correct me if I am wrong). Outside these two, are there other easy to use, and free ones?

Regards.

Comment: Pencil Project now supports Windows stand-alone, along with all other major OSes (Mac, Linux). It's free and open-source: http://pencil.evolus.vn/

Answer (score 10):

[JustInMind](http://www.justinmind.com/) has a free (limited) version.

In terms of tools that are Open Source, [Pencil](http://pencil.evolus.vn/) is the only one I've found.  Have you tried the latest version of Pencil?  When I downloaded it, there was a package installer (as opposed to installing it as a plugin for Firefox directly).  Perhaps it's more standalone now and will work for you?

Answer (score 6):

There is a good thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363/best-tools-for-creating-website-wireframes

Here is the most complete list of such tools I know of. Many of them are free / open source: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools

I am the author of this one (pretty popular): [MockupScreens](http://MockupScreens.com)

Since there are zillion tools, the real question is what you need. Eg. low-fidelity vs. high-fidelity mockups. Or even exporting your mockups to real html/css (which is btw a glorious path to catastrophe most times, especially if used by multiple people). Extensive collaboration (with customer, team) or you are one-man band. Etc.